# Can the expression $x^{2} - 5x + 2$ be rewritten as a special products formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I write $x^{2} - 5x + 2$ as a difference of squares, square of sum or square of difference?

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Are complex numbers allowed?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes ...

Comment: **Proving that the quadratic trinomial can never be the difference of two squares**: We will begin the proof by letting $x^2 - 5x + 2 = a^2 - b^2$. One always has that $$\begin{align} a^2 - b^2 &= a^2 - ab + ab -b^2 \\ &= a(a - b) + b(a - b) \\ &= (a + b)(a - b).\end{align}$$ Therefore, $x^2 - 5x + 2 = (a + b)(a - b)$. By letting $a = x$, we get that $b + -b = 2$ and $-b^2 = -5$. But $5$ is not a square number and for all $b$, one always has that $b + - b= b- b = 0\neq 2$ so we know that $a\neq x$. Or we could try another, but less advanced, approach $\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow$

Comment: Notice that $x^2 - 5x + 2 = x^2 - (5x - 2)$, so then $5x - 2$ has to be a square number. Now the last digit of a square number is always $$0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9.\tag{$\star$}$$ Every number that is a multiple of $5$ ends with a digit $0$ or $5$. If we subtract $2$, we get that $5x - 2$ has a last digit of either $8$ or $3$ (since $0$ corresponds to a multiple of $10$ and $10 - 2 = 8$). Since the last digit of $5x - 2$ is not on the list $(\star)$, then we know that $5x - 2$ will never be a square number. Therefore, the quadratic trinomial $x^2 - 5x + 2 \neq a^2 - b^2$ for $a = x$.

Comment: Above is only true for *strictly integers* $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^2 - 5x +2 = (x - 2.5)^2 - 4.25 = (x - 2.5)^2 - (\sqrt{4.25})^2 = (x - 2.5)^2 + (\sqrt{4.5}i)^2$

Hence, it can be written as difference of squares and sum of square.